# How to Post data with express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a pretty good understanding of how to use the `app.get` function, but I'm having trouble with the `app.post`.
In the following app.js code, should the `/someurl` be the same as in the `action='/acturl'` of my form?

**app.js**

```
app.post('/someurl', function(req, res) {
    var name = req.body.name,
    pass = req.body.pass;
    //save name, pass to db
});
```

**form.jade**

```
form.form-signin(method='post',action='/acturl')
h2.form-signin-heading Please sign in
input.input-block-level(type='text', name='name', placeholder='Username')
input.input-block-level(type='password',name='pass', placeholder='Password')
button.btn.btn-large.btn-primary(type='submit') Sign in
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

allways (yes) --> should the /someurl be the same as in the action='/acturl' of my form?

how can I save the req.body.postvars to a mongo database?

Take a look ta some plugin like http://mongoosejs.com/ (is just an example) for mongodb object modeling.

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks, I actually had it working ... just hadn't run the server. I'm glad it is intuitive!